# Do you get Audio Logs in fixed order?

Tags: crackdown-2

In some games, you get the same message in the same location, and it does not depend on the order you find those locations. In others, you get the messages in correct order (to help with the story flow).

Which way Crackdown 2 does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experiences, the logs do appear to have a fixed collection order, no matter which physical logs you collect first.

For instance, Catalina Thorne's logs are all collected in reverse sequence; the first one you get is her last, and the last one you get is her first.

The whistleblower files come in numerical order, as do the freak watcher's.

The PCNN news reports may seem to be in a random order, but I think that even this order is predetermined; the scant information you get from them fits together too concisely to be coincidence, at least to me.

**The only exception** seems to be the surveillance logs, which contain information about enemy fortifications, and so are location specific.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to depend on the log.  After comparing notes with a friend, it seems that some logs (like the Whistleblower) are always unlocked in order.  Others (like the news anchor) are either random or tied to specific pickup locations.